# Using a pug each loop through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, pug

So I am using NodeJs (with pug as its view engine). My intention is to create a table where an each loop on my pug code adds the data from the **data.json** file in rows on a table.

First let me show you my NodeJs code; I have the following on the **app.js** file (which is my primary entry point to my program)

```
var express = require('express');
var pple = require('data.json');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');


// Get the homepage
router.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    res.render('index', {pple:pple});
});

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log('Listening to port 4000');
});
```

Secondly, I have the following pug code on my **index.pug** file:

```
doctype html

html(lang='en')
  body
    table.table.table-striped
      tr
        th Name
        th Position
        th Address
        th Phone

      each n in pple
        tr
          td= n.name
          td= n.position
          td= n.address
          td= n.phone
```

and this gives me the following result:
[The table I get when I enter the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L0J8.png)

However, here is how my **data.json** file looks like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Person1",
        "position": "Software Eng",
        "address": "Nairobi",
        "phone": "0712121212",
        "foods": {
            "likes": ["fish", "chips"],
            "dislikes": ["pork"]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Person2",
        "position": "Web Dev",
        "address": "Mombasa",
        "phone": "0711223344",
        "foods": {
            "likes": ["checken", "eggs"],
            "dislikes": ["bread"]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Person3",
        "position": "Marketer",
        "address": "Nakuru",
        "phone": "0711121314",
        "foods": {
            "likes": ["peas", "beans"],
            "dislikes": ["weed"]
        }
    }
]
```

and I would like to add extra columns stating the foods they like and dislike. 
As you can see, the foods they like are in two, hence I would like it to display **fish and chips** for person 1, **chicken and eggs** for person 2, and **peas and beans** for person 3; all these on a **Likes** column.

Please help me learn how to add all these in a Likes and Dislikes column. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pug evaluates inline JavaScript, so you can add JavaScript code to format your `foods.likes` and `foods.dislikes.` See https://pugjs.org/language/code.html

The following should do the trick, simply using [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for combining the liked and disliked foods.

```
doctype html

html(lang='en')
  body
    table.table.table-striped
      tr
        th Name
        th Position
        th Address
        th Phone
        th Liked Foods
        th Disliked Foods

      each n in pple
        tr
          td= n.name
          td= n.position
          td= n.address
          td= n.phone
          td= n.food.likes.join(" and ")
          td= n.food.dislikes.join(" and ")
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using [bootstrap grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/), but you could try to add the column food, and under this column add two more columns.

Something like this:

```
doctype html

html(lang='en')
  body
    table.table.table-striped
      tr
        th Name
        th Position
        th Address
        th Phone
        th Food
           tr
             th Likes
             th Dislikes

      each n in pple
        tr
          td= n.name
          td= n.position
          td= n.address
          td= n.phone
          td 
            tr
              td= n.foods.likes
              td= n.foods.dislikes
```

Comment: Sorry, I press a button and I closed the web. I edited the post. I think this should work.